# Circle Cut Off in PictureBox C#

Tags: c#, drawing

i created a function which is drawing a circle with a letter inside.

i write it into a stream and set it to picture box in Zoom Mode.

It looks nice but some pieces of the circle are cut off.

Here is the Code for the Circle:

```
public MemoryStream GenerateCircle(string name)
    {


        var avatarString = string.Format("{0}", name[0]).ToUpper();

        var bgColour = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#007FBC");
        var bmp = new Bitmap(70, 70);
        var sf = new StringFormat();
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        var font = new Font("Arial", 34, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 70, 70);

        Brush b = new SolidBrush(bgColour);
        Pen pen = new Pen(bgColour);

        graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, rect);
        graphics.FillEllipse(b, rect);

        graphics.DrawString(avatarString, font, new SolidBrush(Color.WhiteSmoke), 35, 35, sf);
        graphics.Flush();
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
        return ms;
    }
```

i set it like that:

```
 avatarpicturebox.Image = Image.FromStream(GenerateCircle("Test"));
```

That is what it looks like:

[Circle Cuts Off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmCSW.png)

Can someone help here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reduce the circle's width and height 1 pixel each to avoid clipping the right and bottom sides due to the pixels offset. Use [`Rectangle.Inflate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.inflate?view=net-6.0) method and pass negative width and height values to shrink the destination rectangle to fit.

Modifying your function to return a `Bitmap` instead of `MemoryStream`.

```cs
public Bitmap GenerateCircle(string name)
{
    var bgColour = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#007FBC");
    var bmp = new Bitmap(70, 70, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    using (var sf = new StringFormat())
    using (var font = new Font("Arial", 34, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel))
    using (var b = new SolidBrush(bgColour))
    using (var pen = new Pen(bgColour))
    {
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

        graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size);
        rect.Inflate(-2, -2);

        graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, rect);
        graphics.FillEllipse(b, rect);                
        graphics.DrawString(name.ToUpper(), font, Brushes.WhiteSmoke, rect, sf);
    }

    return bmp;
}
```

And the caller:

```cs
private void SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    avatarpicturebox.Image?.Dispose();
    avatarpicturebox.Image = GenerateCircle("T");
}
```

**Side Notes**

- Always dispose of the graphics objects you create either by calling explicitly the `.Dispose` method or by creating them with [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using) keyword.
- Use the [`Graphics.DrawString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#overloads) overloads that take a `Rectangle` and [`StringFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Drawing.StringFormat.%2523ctor)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) params to draw the strings. Use the later to dictate how and where the string should be drawn in the given `Rectangle`. See also [`StringFormatFlags`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformatflags?view=netframework-4.8) enum.